# how to set alignment in pandas in python with non-ANSI characters

Tags: python, pandas

When i read the data(death in M370 air crash) in R ,the format is fine.

```
> read.csv("g:\\test.ansi",sep=",")
           乘客姓名 性别   出生日期
1      HuangTianhui   男 1948/05/28
2             姜翠云   女 1952/03/27
3             李红晶   女 1994/12/09
4          LuiChing   女 1969/08/02
5             宋飞飞   男 1982/03/01
6             唐旭东   男 1983/08/03
7        YangJiabao   女 1988/08/25
```

when i read the data  in python ,how can i set the records right alignment?

```
>>> import pandas as pd    
>>> pd.read_csv("g:\\test.ansi",sep=",")
          乘客姓名         性别 出生日期
0    HuangTianhui  男  1948/05/28
1             姜翠云  女  1952/03/27
2             李红晶  女  1994/12/09
3        LuiChing  女  1969/08/02
4             宋飞飞  男  1982/03/01
5             唐旭东  男  1983/08/03
6      YangJiabao  女  1988/08/25
7        买买提江·阿布拉  男  1979/07/10
```

The data is here:  http://pan.baidu.com/s/1sjHauL3

Comment: Can you show how the `test.ansi` file looks like?

Comment: On IPython notebook when you display the dataframe it outputs it left-aligned which would appear correct, however when you output the first column, you can see that it doesn't align, if you remove the western strings, so keep just chinese characters, then it aligns correctly, this looks like a problem with either mixing character sets (although I would expect it to treat everything as unicode) or a character width issue with mixed character sets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that when dealing with Chinese characters (which takes the space of two ANSI characters), `pandas` still padding the amount of white space for ANSI characters. This means that the number of white spaces is only half of what is needed for a DF containing Chinese characters. What makes the situation worse it that `pandas` ignored that the Chinese characters takes twice the space:

```
print pd.read_csv("test.ansi",sep=",", encoding='gb18030').loc[10:12]

10  边亮京  男  1987/06/06
11  边茂勤  女  1947/07/19
12   曹蕊  女  1982/02/19
#notice how the last line is missing one leading white space compared to the preceding lines.
```

Ultimately, under the hood it all come down to the `__unicode__` class of the `DataFrame` class which allocates spaces according to the `_repr_fit_horizontal_` class. I am not sure what may be the best solution. Using two spaces in stead of one anywhere when a Chinese character is encountered? That is not a good idea in the case of mixing rows, some with and some without Chinese characters, such as in this `dataframe`.

Maybe worthwhile to report this as a bug.

But if you use `IPython` notebook, you are less affected by this issue, as `DataFrames` are nicely displayed as HTML.

Answer (score 4):

I have also encountered this problem. After looking into the rendering code of dataframe, I found the following method in pandas(v0.25) source code:

```
def _get_adjustment():
    use_east_asian_width = get_option("display.unicode.east_asian_width")
    if use_east_asian_width:
        return EastAsianTextAdjustment()
    else:
        return TextAdjustment()
```

So the solution is setting the option before you want to print dataframes containing CJK chars.

```
import pandas as pd

your_df = pd.read_csv('some_path.txt') # load data into dataframe
pd.set_option("display.unicode.east_asian_width", True)
print(your_df)
```

After applying it on your data, it works.

[image: not setting this option]

[image: setting this option to True]