# how to read "\n\n" in python module pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

There is a data file which has `\n\n` at the end of every line.
http://pan.baidu.com/s/1o6jq5q6
My system:win7+python3.3+R-3.0.3
In R

```
sessionInfo()

[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936 
[2] LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                                                   
[5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_People's Republic of China.936
```

In python: chcp  936

I can read it in R.

```
read.table("test.pandas",sep=",",header=TRUE)
```

It is so simple.

and I can read it in python to get almost same output.

```
fr=open("g:\\test.pandas","r",encoding="gbk").read()
data=[x for x in fr.splitlines() if x.strip() !=""]
for id,char in enumerate(data):
    print(str(id)+","+char)
```

When i read it in python module pandas,

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv("test.pandas",sep=",",encoding="gbk")
```

I found two problems in  the output:
1)how to make right alignment(the problem i have asked in other post)
[how to set alignment in pandas in python with non-ANSI characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23008636/how-to-set-alignment-in-pandas-in-python)
2)there is a NaN line in every real data.

Can i improve my pandas code to get better display in console?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your file when read with `open('test.pandas', 'rb')` seems to contain '\r\r\n' as its line terminators. Python 3.3 does seem to convert this to '\n\n' while Python 2.7 converts it to '\r\n' when read with `open('test.pandas', 'r', encoding='gbk')`.

[pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=lineterminator) does have a lineterminator parameter but it only accepts single character terminators.

What you can do is process the file a bit before passing it to `pandas.read_csv()`, and you can use [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/io.html?#io.StringIO) which will wrap a string buffer in a file interface so that you don't need to write out a temporary file first.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

with open('test.pandas', 'r', encoding='gbk') as in_file:
    contents = in_file.read().replace('\n\n', '\n')

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(contents))
```

(I don't have the GBK charset for the output below.)

```
>>> df[0:10]
          ??????? ???    ????????
0    HuangTianhui  ??  1948/05/28
1          ??????   ?  1952/03/27
2             ???   ?  1994/12/09
3        LuiChing   ?  1969/08/02
4            ????  ??  1982/03/01
5            ????  ??  1983/08/03
6      YangJiabao   ?  1988/08/25
7  ??????????????  ??  1979/07/10
8          ??????   ?  1949/10/20
9           ???»?   ?  1951/10/21
```

In Python 2.7 `StringIO()` was in module `StringIO` instead of `io`.

Comment: Ive got this same problem `\r\n` in `to_html` output so thanks for the post. However I get `AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'replace'` on `contents = contents.replace('\n\n', '\n')`

Comment: Yup. Same. Least you can do is check if your code works.